# PySpark parse array of objects (JSON format) to one column df

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an array of nested JSON objects like that:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "n": {}
  }
]
```

I would like to read this JSON file (multiline) into spark DataFrame with one column. Where the column has *StringType* and contains a JSON object:

```
+----------+
|   json   |
+----------+
| {"a": 1, |
| "n": {}} |
+----------+
```

I tried to do the following:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("json", StringType(), True)])
spark.read.json('test.json', multiLine=True).show()
```

But it didn't work. Are there  any options to do that in PySpark?

Comment: you should go with `spark.read.option('multiline', True).text('test.json').show()`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, well, it actually reads the whole array into one row. I want read each object into different row.

Comment: can you update with example?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, done

Comment: what is the usefulness with that kind of dataframe? how you will proceed after that?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, I will do thrift serialization and write it to Kafka.

Comment: can't you serialize `[{"a": 1, "n": {}}]` as string and write to kafka? which would be more beneficial than the format you are thinking of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution myself:

```
json_schema = StructType([
  StructField("json", StringType(), True)
])
df.toJSON().map(lambda x: [x]).toDF(schema=json_schema).show()
```